# How to display errors with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a fairly simple website that I am playing with using ASP.NET Core.   I am running the application from the command line and the website is returning static files but I keep getting 500 errors when I attempt to make a request that should get handled by MVC.    How do I see what the error is?   Whether the error is displayed to the browser or logged to the console doesn't matter I just want a way to see what the error is.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Add the error page middleware as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Comment: What namespace is UseErrorPage in?   I added Microsoft.Own to my asp.net vnext web project but no UseErrorPage.   This is what is on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn253556(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics`. See https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics

Comment: It is now in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics`

Comment: !!Make sure that app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); is at the VERY BEGINNING of the Configure Section of Startup.cs!!

Comment: If you get `startup` errors you can enable extra startup options to output the actual reason. Have a look at my blog post about it. http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/asp-net-core-how-to-fix-error-occurred.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me, still shows 'An error occurred' with no details

Answer (score 22):

**Update for beta8:**
In beta8 Microsoft changed the name to `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`. So if you want to use the ErrorPage, call:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Here is the link to the related [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/63).
The `ErrorPageOptions` are the same as in beta6/7.

---

You can use

```
app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll)
```

until **beta5** of Asp.Net Mvc.

---

As of **beta6**, `ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll` has been removed. You can now use the version without parameters

```
app.UseErrorPage();
```

or create an ErrorPageOptions object and specify how many lines around the error you want to display by setting SourceCodeLineCount.

```
app.UseErrorPage(new ErrorPageOptions() {SourceCodeLineCount = 100});
```

---

**Additional Information**

They removed multiple properties of `ErrorPageOptions` in [this commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/commit/0da9e2bec5f991f526edc729b8b73c0dbb8b2876).

Before:

```
public class ErrorPageOptions
{
    private bool _defaultVisibility;

    private bool? _showExceptionDetails;
    private bool? _showSourceCode;
    private bool? _showQuery;
    private bool? _showCookies;
    private bool? _showHeaders;
    private bool? _showEnvironment;
    ...
}
```

After:

```
public class ErrorPageOptions
{
    public int SourceCodeLineCount { get; set; }
    public IFileProvider FileProvider { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

So now you can only set how many lines of source code are printed.

Comment: This must of changed again, as i am using beta7 and i have the options for showExceptionDetails, showSourceCode etc and also SourceCodeLineCount

Comment: You have? Are you sure you are using beta7? I looked at its source code on Github a few days ago and did find only the code I posted here. 
But I will have another look at it nonetheless

Comment: @user2736022 I checked again, I dont have the option in beta7. Could you post some code where you use ErrorPageOptions and what namespaces you include?

Comment: In beta 8 and visual studio 2015 it is now added by default in Startup.cs if (env.IsDevelopment())

Answer (score 13):

If you don't care that your error details would be exposed to the world, you can enable the error details, right in the browser without any code changes. (**This was only tested in `IIS 8.5`**):

- In `IIS Manager`, in the left `Connections` section, left-click select your `Site`.
- In the right side `Feature View` open `Error Pages`.
- On the far right `Actions` section, click on `Edit Feature Settings`
- In the `Error Responses`, select the 2nd, `Detailed errors`, option then `Ok` (or if you are worried about exposing stuff to the world, start with the 3rd option, if you can open a local browser... ie, localhost:...)

This should be enough for you to be able to see the exact error... **Important**: If you had to use the middle `Detailed errors` option, be sure to turn it off once you debug the problem. This can give a hacker all he needs to break into your server.

Comment: This is very convenient, where you don't have to redeploy your site.

Answer (score -3):

If it is not important to expose the detail of the error to the world, then you can activate detailed error page in web.config.

Just add `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in the `<configuration>` / `<system.web>` of your web.config file located in root folder of your web site.

For more detailed explanation:
[How to Use Web.Config customErrors for ASP.NET](https://stackify.com/web-config-customerrors-asp-net/)

This has the advantage that you don't have to redeploy your site

Comment: This is not relevant to the question by OP. He is using .NET Core and your answer is for ASP.NET

Comment: This also works for ASP.Net. web.config settings takes precedence. I wouldn't do it though, seems like a bad practice... or at least, ugly.