# ASP.NET Core Running as Windows Service gets 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, service

I'm trying to implement an ASP.NET Core application as a Windows service. I'm basically following the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service#next-steps). I publish the app, then create the service pointing to the executable in the publish location. The service gets created successfully. I start the service and that is also successful. However, when I try to navigate a browser to the URL I set up, I get a "500 - Internal Server Error". I'm pretty new to this process and I don't really know how to track this down. Here is how I set up my entry point:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var isDebug = Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug");
        string runPath = isDebug ?
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() :
            Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(runPath)
            .UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(runPath, "wwwroot"))
            .UseUrls(new string[] { "http://myserver:9191" })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        if (isDebug)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
        else
        {
            host.RunAsService();
        }
    }
```

FYI, I've tried it with and without the UseWebRoot line, and I've tried UseWebRoot with both a relative and an absolute path. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is more info needed?

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: Checkout this thread https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1386

Comment: Enable detailed error output for a description of the cause if the 500 error, see [How to display errors with ASP.NET Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563493/how-to-display-errors-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: Thanks Alex! The error seems to be "The view 'Index' not found". So it's not finding that content. I looked in my publish location and sure enough, the view files aren't in there anywhere. Could I be missing some sort of setup or config to get my view files published (or copied into wwwroot maybe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, commenters! Turns out I had not added the views structure to my publishOptions in my project.json. That section now looks like this:

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "web.config",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json"
]}
```

Everything seems to work now!