# When debugging I get error code 404 when trying to call a JsonResult in .Net Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core

When Trying to get a JsonResult from my controller I get error code 404, from my front end and from Postman. My method isn't being hit at all while debugging.

I Have added [HttpPost] above my methods and that results is the 404 error removing it creates a 500 error

```
    {
        public UserDetailsService _userDetailsService;

        public UserDetailsController(UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
        {
            _userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetCountries()
        {
            // run synchronously as partials cannot use async
            Task<IEnumerable<ViewModels.CountriesSelectList>> task = Task.Run(async () => await _userDetailsService.GetCountriesSelectListAsync());
            var results = task.Result;

            return Json(results);
        }
```

I expect the json result to return a list back to the front end once it has fired

Update:My route that I use is https://localhost:44323/userdetails/getcountries
In the startup.cs it is configured as 
`routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Intel}/{action=Introduction}/{id?}");`

Comment: error 500 can be an execution error. Enable error reporting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display errors with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563493/how-to-display-errors-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: I checked and my Startup.cs and it does contain app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() so it is not an error display problem

Comment: Then, what is the error message ?

Comment: Hey Dominic, it's hard for us to help when you haven't provided the endpoint you are hitting. Show us the route, and also the controller name/route

Comment: The error message is 405 which usually means methods not allowed with the research that I have done

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt the [HttpPost] be [HttpGet]? (Since you're trying to retrieve data)